# "Invalid use of undefined type" error

Tags: c

These are two errors I get, can someone explain to me why my thinking is wrong?

```
HW3.c: In function ‘newStack’:
HW3.c:23:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct stack’
   myStack.list = malloc(sizeof(job) * 16);

HW3.c:24:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct stack’
   &job1 = myStack.list;
```

The reason I did

```c
&job1 = myStack.list;
```

is because I thought that's the same thing as `myStack.list = &job1` and when I want to add more jobs, I can code something like

```c
&job2 = myStack.list + sizeof(job);
```

As for the first error, I'm just at a loss.

```c
typedef struct {
    int phaseAndDuration[2][16];
    int currentPhase;
    int isCompleted;
} job;

typedef struct {
    struct job* list;
    int currentIndex;
    int size;
} stack;

struct stack myStack;
struct job job1;

void newStack(void)
{
    myStack.list = malloc(sizeof(job) * 16);
    &job1 = myStack.list;
    myStack.currentIndex = 0;
}

void pop(void)
{
}

void push(void)
{
    if(myStack.size != 0)
    {
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who taught you to say `typedef struct`?

Comment: What are you trying here `&job1 = myStack.list;`?

Comment: If you use `typedef struct` then you dont need to put struct in front of the variable declaration. Thats the entire point of using `typedef`...

Comment: `&job1 = myStack.list;` is not at all the same as `myStack.list = &job1;` In C (and other imperative languages), the left hand side is what you assign *to* and the right hand side is what is being assigned. You really need to consider a basic C tutorial or book to help straighten out some of the fundamentals.

Comment: In C language `struct stack` and simply `stack` are two different things. In your code you defined type `stack`. Just `stack`. Later you attempt to use `struct stack`. Why??? You never defined `struct stack`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that you `typedef` an anonymous `struct` and the try to declare it as if it were not anonymous or `typedef`ed, you need to change the declarations to

```
stack myStack;
```

because the `struct` has no name, you only defined a type named `stack` which is what you can use to declare a variable, if it were

```
typedef struct stack 
{
    /* ... */
} stack;
```

you could use both, and without the `typedef` you would only be allowed to use `struct stack`.

Also, the expression

```
&job1 = myStack.list;
```

is invalid, because `&job1` is not an l-value and you cannot assign to it. In fact if it were to compile it would mean something that is not really possible which is overwrite the address of a stack variable.

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `typedef`, as in:

```
typedef struct {

    // (your fields here)

}stack;
```

then, after that you use your struct as just `stack`, like this:

```
stack myStack;
```

...because you have **defined** `stack` to be an equivalent of `struct {...`. does it make sense?

Alternatively, if you want to keep using `struct`, you can make your structured tagged instead of anonymous, like:

```
struct t_Stack {

    // (your fields here)

};

struct t_Stack myStack;
```

Comment: My plain-old-C might be a bit rusty, so feel free to point any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two types `stack` and `job` defined via `typedef`, not `struct stack` nor `struct job`.

```
&job1 = myStack.list;
```

is bad because `&job1` is just a pointer value, not an variable, and the compiler won't know where to store the data.

Not knowing what is meant by "add more jobs",

```
&job2 = myStack.list + sizeof(job);
```

Might be bad because the addition to pointer move the pointer to `sizeof(job)`th element after `myStack.list`.
Maybe you want to do

```
job2 = myStack.list + 1;
```

to have `job2` point the next element after `myStack.list`.

Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* add this to use malloc() */

typedef struct {
    int phaseAndDuration[2][16];
    int currentPhase;
    int isCompleted;
} job;

typedef struct {
    job* list;
    int currentIndex;
    int size;
} stack;

stack myStack;
job *job1;

void newStack(void)
{
    myStack.list = malloc(sizeof(job) * 16);
    job1 = myStack.list;
    myStack.currentIndex = 0;
}

void pop(void)
{
}

void push(void)
{
    if(myStack.size != 0)
    {
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```